# scroll x is not working in css

Tags: css

I am facing problem of scroll-x in css

Please find below html code

```
<div id=main_user_chat_tab_div class="chat-container_div" style="border:4px solid #F00;">
    <div id="chat_box_win" class="chat_box_win" style="position:relative;"></div>
    <div id="chat_user_rec" style="width:100%; height:20%; border:3px solid #333;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll; display:table-row; position:relative;">        
        <div id="user_chat_image"></div>
        <div id="user_chat_image"></div>
        <div id="user_chat_image"></div>
        <div id="user_chat_image"></div>
        <div id="user_chat_image"></div>
        <div id="user_chat_image"></div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

css code:

```
 .chat-container_div {
    width: 20.2%;    
    height:72%;
    margin-right:15%;
    margin-top:11%;
    float:right;
    position:relative;
    display:none;
  }



#user_chat_image {

    position:relative;
    display:inline;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
    border-radius: 50px;
    bottom:0px;
    float:right; margin-right:2%; width:60px; height:60px;  display:block;
}
```

In below screen I want scroll-x when outer div **chat_user_rec** will full. But in below screen it is not working, overflow div are adding into next row. Please do you have any idea about it. I think something is happing wrong.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, I believe you should be using `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent element to get the desired effect. Take a look here: [Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwwVYM)

I simplified your example a bit. First, the HTML:

```
<div id=main_user_chat_tab_div class="chat-container_div" style="border:4px solid #F00;">
  <div id="chat_box_win" class="chat_box_win" style="position:relative;"></div>
  <div id="chat_user_rec" style="width:auto; height:20%;overflow-y:hidden;overflow-x:scroll; display:block; position:relative; white-space: nowrap; text-align: right;">
    <div class="user_chat_image"></div>
    <div class="user_chat_image"></div>
    <div class="user_chat_image"></div>
    <div class="user_chat_image"></div>
    <div class="user_chat_image"></div>
    <div class="user_chat_image"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
.chat-container_div {
  width: 20.2%;
  height: 72%;
  margin-right: 15%;
  margin-top: 11%;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
}

.user_chat_image {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  background: red;
  -moz-border-radius: 50px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  margin-right: 2%;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
}
```

Note: you're using the ID improperly for `user_chat_image`, so you should switch it over to a class in both the HTML and the CSS, as I have here.

I would also recommend moving all of the styling into the CSS file and out of the HTML.

Comment: Updated both the answer and the Codepen to more closely resemble your original code, and both are working. Make sure you read the notes at the bottom about switching `user_chat_image` to a class and moving styles into the CSS file to keep things neat.

Comment: Andrew thanks for help,
your above suggestion are working fine but now suppose there is only one div **<div class="user_chat_image"></div>** in **chat_user_rec** and i want to add divs dynamically by programming via creating new div and append the div in **chat_user_rec**. i tried but scroll is not working. please suggest your point